# Controlling Ship Rotation as it Orbits a Target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity-component-system

I am trying to get my ship entities to either look in the direction they are moving or at the target they are orbiting around. At this point I would be happy with either result. Unfortunately I simply don't seem to understand the underlying math enough despite all of my Google research on how to accomplish this.

This is what I currently have in my RotateSystem

```
public void Execute(ref Translation shipPosition, ref Ship ship, ref Rotation rotation)
{

      ship.Theta += .0075f;
      float3 delta = new float3(
          ship.Radius * Mathf.Sin(ship.Theta) * Mathf.Cos(ship.Phi),
          ship.Radius * Mathf.Cos(ship.Theta),
          ship.Radius * Mathf.Sin(ship.Theta) * Mathf.Sin(ship.Phi));


      rotation.Value = Quaternion.Slerp(rotation.Value,
          Quaternion.LookRotation(ship.OrbitTarget + delta-shipPosition.Value),0.5f);


      shipPosition.Value = ship.OrbitTarget + delta;           

}
```

The result of this is that ships face their orbit target 1/2 of the time and face away the other half of the time.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the second parameter, `Quaternion.LookRotation` assumes you want the local `up` to be as close to `Vector3.up` as possible. Instead, use the direction from the orbiting body to the orbited body:

```
public void Execute(ref Translation shipPosition, ref Ship ship, ref Rotation rotation)
{

    ship.Theta += .0075f;
    float3 delta = new float3(
            ship.Radius * Mathf.Sin(ship.Theta) * Mathf.Cos(ship.Phi),
            ship.Radius * Mathf.Cos(ship.Theta),
            ship.Radius * Mathf.Sin(ship.Theta) * Mathf.Sin(ship.Phi));

    Vector3 previousPos = shipPosition.Value;

    shipPosition.Value = ship.OrbitTarget + delta;   

    rotation.Value = Quaternion.Slerp(rotation.Value, Quaternion.LookRotation(
            shipPosition.Value - previousPos,
            ship.OrbitTarget - shipPosition.Value), 0.5f);
}
```